# iOS: Performance of reloading UIImage(name:...)

Tags: ios, uiimage

I have a tableview and each row has an icon. 
90% of the rows have the same icon.

In the cellForRowAtIndexPath method I load the image from an assets folder like this:

```
var cellImage = UIImage(named: "MyImage")
```

Does this pose a performance problem? Is the OS somehow smart enough to now that it's the same image each time? Would it be better if I loaded the image once and saved it in a class variable and assigned it each time?

Comment: As long you you do not see any issues: Opinion based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIImage`'s `named:` API actually ***DOES*** do some kind of caching.

If you look at [UIImage's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiimage), it states:

> Use the `init(named:in:compatibleWith:)` method (or the `init(named:)`
>   method) to create an image from an image asset or image file located
>   in your app’s main bundle (or some other known bundle). **Because these
>   methods cache the image data automatically, they are especially
>   recommended for images that you use frequently.**